# How to access delegate properties in ListView using index

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I want to access delegate properties in `ListView`. I've tried with `contentItem` but sometimes it's `undefined`.

**Here is my code:**

```
ListModel{
            id: modeldata
            ListElement{
                name:"don"
                rank:1
            }
            ListElement{
                name:"shan"
                rank:2
            }
            ListElement{
                name:"james"
                rank:3
            }
            ListElement{
                name:"jeggu"
                rank:4
            }
        }
        Component{
            id: delegateitem
            Row {
                property int count: rank
                Rectangle{
                    width: 100
                    height: 50
                    Text{
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ListView{
            id: listview
            focus: true
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: modeldata
            delegate: delegateitem
            onCurrentIndexChanged: {
        console.log("position",currentIndex)
        console.log("property",contentItem.children[currentIndex].count);
            }
        }
```

**Problem invalid output at position 1**

```
qml: position 0
qml: property 1
qml: position 1
qml: property undefined
qml: position 2
qml: property 2
qml: position 3
qml: property 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: if you are trying to access list elements from outside your list, this is a good indicator that you should rethink your desing.

Now the solution: a listview has more children than only its items. You can filter them out by defining a property "property string type: "myType" " for example. Then find the items by looping over the children and only take those where the type property equals "myType".
Its somewhat of a hack but again you should really not be doing this in the first place.

Comment: this will be awkward to code up and slow to run. If I'm wrong, perhaps provide a code sample to demonstrate

Comment: I really want to know what it is, although I know that I should go to the source.

Answer (score 7):

@Teimpz didn't really explain it well. Especially since there are bunch of qt project and ubuntu touch qml examples and use cases where you manage dynamically created list elements using javascript, and that is why they have javascript methods and properties

In QML there is more a notion of parent than a child, which is common in html. In bigger projects it is recommended (as you can also see in qt examples and in docs http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-expressions.html#functions-in-imported-javascript-files) to have js logic separate from qml elements so you do access and manage elements from outside rather than pollute you qml elements with js logic, but not in a way of looking for children elements, but rather exposing children elements that you need.

In your case you should just use `currentItem`, same as you use currentIndex, so `currentItem.count` will give you what you need.
And if you don't need current item at all, you can access elements from model directly:

`modelData.get(currentIndex).count`, or `listview.model.get(currentIndex).count`

As for the hack that is mentioned by @Teimpz that is also one bad example. When you have more complex requirements and wanting specific elements inside delegate, every delegate has ListView.isCurrentItem property which you can attach and check. This would mean you can add property var myTargetItem to listview, and set it from child to whatever element you want if that delegate is current http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#isCurrentItem-attached-prop

You can of course do that for any kind of event, maybe activeFocus so you could only reference activeFocused item.

This once again give you ability to expose only wanted elements without any advanced logic or lopping. Combining this with signals you can create very complex but clean interfaces without searching through children items.

So in the end maybe less nice but still better than searching for elements would be to add `property int currentItemCount: 0` to listview. In delegate (Row element) you then add `property bool isCurrentItem: ListView.isCurrentItem`
so you get `onIsCurrentItemChanged` signal inside delegate, where you can do:

`onIsCurrentItemChanged: if(isCurrentItem) listview.currentItemCount = count`

so you have your current item count always set

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is using [`itemAtIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-listview.html#itemAtIndex-method) like `intemAt()` in `Repeater`.

Answer (score -1):

```
myListView.itemAtIndex(currentIndex)).function_name()
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.