# Access listview model data in the delegate of another listview with a different model in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, model, qml

The issue:
I got two listviews in qml, both have models implemented in C++ based on the QAbstractListModel.

As an example, say both listviews only have two roles, color and size, and both of these are dynamic and can change from some outside data input (i.e tcp client).
Each item in the second listview is related to the first one where any element in the second listview will contain the index of one of the elements in the first listview.
The second listview wants to not only show its own roles, but also the the color and size of the element from the first listview, of which it has the index of stored.

How can you dynamically update this value in the second listview?

I have med some setters and getters and can populate the data when I first instantiate the second listview, but after that any changes to the properties in the first listview will not be shown in the second listview, because this listview is not connected the the data in the first list and will not update when the data updates.

The question is then more specifically how can I connect these two? Preferably without updating the entire second listview but just the delegate that is connected to a changing element from the first list.

If this text example is confusing I can try and make some code to explain further.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access delegate properties in ListView using index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810330/how-to-access-delegate-properties-in-listview-using-index)

Comment: It doesnt really solve it for me, and the selected answer is pretty vague in how to implement aswell. Answer below has the partial answer, so will go for that with some edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the answer above with what I wrote in the comment, using the itemAtIndex, but this will not update the property in the second list when new data arrives.

I got this working by creating a function in the delegate of the second list that searches in the child items of the contentItem of the first list, and then binding the role from there, like this:

```
function getDelegateInstanceAt(index) {
                    var len = cameraList.contentItem.children.length;
                    if(len > 0 && index > -1 && index < len) {
                        return cameraList.contentItem.children[index];
                    } else {
                        return undefined;
                    }
                }
property text firstListName: getDelegateInstanceAt(storedFirstListIndex).name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate can access the `index` of itself in the ListView, which you can use with the others' ListView `itemAtIndex` function.

Bind the model data role you want with a property in the delegate of the first list, and use that in the second list delegate, i.e

```
// In the delegate of the first listview, named firstList
property text nameBind: name
```

and

```
// In the delegate of the second listview, where storedIndex is an index of an element in the first listview.
text: firstList.itemAtIndex(storedIndex).nameBind
```

Comment: in which case you would have to add a property to it, like 'itemData' which can then be accessed (`model` is not usable since name-clashing)

Comment: True, you might also use that index with the model itself

Comment: I tried it with itemAtIndex and had to add property bindings to each of my model roles, but it works, by adding in my first list delegate "property bool colorCopy: color". Then accessing it with firstList.itemAtIndex(storedIndex).colorCopy in my second list delegate. Will set as solution if you edit (or I can do it if not, with basically Amfasis comment)

Comment: actually binding it to anotjher property in the second list won't make it update on new data, seems like I have to call the entire function with itemAtIndex every time.

Comment: Finally figured it out, I had an iteration of my solution which wasn't this solution. This will not work, so I will remove my edit and answer it myself.